# explicit specialization with concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to use concepts to do explicit specialization of some template method, but it isn't compiled on [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/b9h9zsP9E) or [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/qxv3ETT3T), but can compile on [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/E1ff58a17)... Who is right?

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> 
concept arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && !std::is_same_v<T, bool>;

template<typename T>
void foo(const T &value, int &result);

template<>
void foo(const arithmetic auto &value, int &result) {

}
```

Comment: The newest version of all 3 can do concepts see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20

Comment: but I tried latest version of all 3, check links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
template<arithmetic T>
void foo(const T &value, int &result){}
```

or

```
void foo(const arithmetic auto &value, int &result){}
```

So no `template<>` or `template<arithmetic T>`

Comment: The placement of `const` is misleading in the second option (and not ideal in the first). The const modifier is not on the concept, but the type. I would suggest writing it as `arithmetic auto const &value`.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit specializations can’t have the template parameter implied by `const arithmetic auto`; Clang is wrong, perhaps in that it is ignoring the `template<>` and just **overloading** the template like you probably want to do.

Comment: Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo: You overload a template by removing the `template<>` that I said it was ignoring.